# Need help to determine if a given algorithm is iterative or recursive

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, iteration, quicksort

so I got a project for a computer science module, and they ask us to perform ITERATIVE quick and merge sorts, so I wrote an algorithm, but I am unsure if it is iterative or recursive.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Here is the algorithm (it works, just need to know if it is iterative or not)

```
public static void quickSort(ArrayList<school> x){

    if(x.isEmpty()){        
        return ;
    }
    
    ArrayList<school> smaller = new ArrayList<>();     
    ArrayList<school> greater = new ArrayList<>();      

    school pivot = x.get(0);        // pivot value
    int i;      // incremental counter
    school j;       // looping value

    for( i=1; i < x.size();i++){
        j = x.get(i);                                       
        if( j.getName().compareTo(pivot.getName()) < 0 ){       
            smaller.add(j);
        }else{
            greater.add(j);
        }
    }

    quickSort(smaller);
    quickSort(greater);

    x.clear();

    x.addAll(smaller);
    x.add(pivot);
    x.addAll(greater);

}
```

Comment: _Recursive_ functions call themselves (possibly indirectly). That they contain a bit of iteration does not  make their category _iterative_.

Comment: Iterative quick sort uses a stack to avoid recursion, where pairs of indexes are pushed onto and popped from the stack. Iterative merge sort normally means [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `quickSort` function is called from within itself, therefore this is recursive.